# Как лучше добавлять элементы в bytearray

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код на Си

```
for (int i = 0, int j = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    switch (buf[i])
    {
    case '[':
    case ']':
    case '\\':
        tbuf[j++] = '\\';
        tbuf[j++] = ~buf[i];
        break;
    default:
        tbuf[j++] = buf[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Как его правильно переписать на python?

```
for i in buf:
    if i in b'[]\\':
        tbuf += b'\\' + bytes((~i & 0xFF, ))
    else:
        tbuf += bytes((i, ))
```

В данном варианте не нравится преобразование к `bytes` через кортеж, использование операции `& 0xFF` для ограничения значения переменной

Comment: Чем вас не устроил ваш вариант переписывания?

Comment: преобразование к bytes через кортеж, использование операции & 0xFF для ограничения значения переменной

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для добавления одного байта (как числа) к `bytearray` можно использовать метод `append`.

По поводу операции `~i & 0xFF` - это инвертирование бит (замена 0 на 1 и наоборот) в пределах одного байта, это можно сделать с помощью применения к числу битового XOR со значением 0xFF, получится на одну операцию меньше.

```
tbuf = bytearray()

for i in buf:
    if i in b'[]\\':
        tbuf += b'\\'
        tbuf.append(i ^ 0xFF)
    else:
        tbuf.append(i)
```